# Reconstructing an ellipse from an arc, synthetically

Tags: plane-geometry, conic-sections, geometric-constructions

Given only an arc of a circle, we can easily reconstruct it fully without any use of analytic geometry - indeed using only compass and straightedge. Note that by "given only an arc", we mean that "from a circle that was originally drawn on the plane, everything except an arc got erased".

**Question:** Given an arc of an ellipse, can we reconstruct it without using analytic or algebraic geometry but *synthetically* - using objects not restricted to compass and straightedge (for example, one could use threads)?

**Sub-questions:** Does it matter if the arc is more than half of the full ellipse? What if more than one arc, say 2 arcs, of the ellipse are given (here, we mean the arcs given only as broken off fragments of the wireframe boundary of the ellipse and their relative position is not known)?

Note: analogous questions could be asked about the other conic sections.

Comment: Why mathoverflow and not https://math.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Five points in general position lie on a unique conic. With the help of Pascal's theorem one can construct arbitrarily many points on the same conic.

EDIT. Answering the question about construction of the foci: yes, it is possible. If 5 points on a conic are given, then the coefficients of the corresponding quadratic polynomial are constructible: solution of a linear system requires only rational functions of the coefficients. The center and the principal axes are constructible: rational functions plus square root extraction when finding the eigenvectors. Ellipse vertices are constructible: intersection of a line with a conic requires square roots and arithmetic operations only. The foci are constructible: for the focal distance arithmetic operations and square roots only are needed.

The above results in a terribly long algorithm. I am sure that the descriptive geometers knew a shorter construction in the 19th century already.

Comment: I understand what you mean is this: given five points A, B, C, D, E on the conic, find the intersection of AB with ED (call this point P), choose a point Q on BC, extend PQ to meet CD at say R. Then, the point of intersection of  EQ and AR, say F will lie on the conic. Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify if this approach can be extended to find the foci of the ellipse? Then, one could physically draw the ellipse as a continuous curve. That I guess would fully complete the answer.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. hopefully the possible 19th century reconstruction methods could be rediscovered!